# installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

When I'm trying make `apt upgrade` It returns that is 4 not fully installed packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu26.8) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up gconf2-common (3.2.6-6ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package gconf2-common (--configure):
 installed gconf2-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up gdm3 (3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 installed gdm3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not installed.
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 gconf2-common
 gdm3
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried force install `sudo apt-get reinstall -f gconf2-common grub-pc gdm3` but it fails in the same way

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: @Hackeron Only which I found it's remove `.postinst` files from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` for problematic packages. e.g. `grub-pc.postinst` file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only solutions which I found it's remove `.postinst` files from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` for problematic packages. e.g. `grub-pc.postinst` file

Comment: spent hours on this, thank you. What bad things this is going to cause as a side effect?

Comment: This works, although the same error about that file will show up when you upgrade grub-pc again.